# Seaborn/Matplotlib - Only Showing Certain X Values in FacetGrid

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, facet

I am trying to create a facet of charts that show total scores over time, in seconds.  X axis is the time in seconds and y axis is the total score.

As you can see, I am restricting the output to 2 1/2 minutes via xlim .

What I would like to do is to only show values on the xaxis for every 30 seconds (i.e. 30, 60, 90, 120, 150).. I still want to show the values of (for example) 10 and 15 seconds on the chart, just not on the labels on the xaxis.

How do I modify the code below to do this?  Been trying various forms of xticks and xlabel but just can't figure it out.. Google has not been my friend either..

Would really appreciate some help

Thanks

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Subject': ['Math', 'Math', 'Math','Math', 'Math', 'Math', 'Math','Math', 'Math', 'Math','English', 'English', 'English','English', 'English', 'English', 'English','English', 'English', 'English'], 
               'timeinseconds': [1, 10, 15, 30, 45, 60, 90, 120, 140, 150,1, 10, 15, 30, 45, 60, 90, 120, 140, 150], 
               'totalscore': [.2, .3, .4, .37, .45, .55, .60, .54, .63, .72,
               .4, .34, .23, .52, .56, .59, .63, .66, .76, .82]})

g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="Subject", col_wrap=5, size=3.5, ylim=(0, 1),xlim=(0,360))
g = g.map(sns.pointplot, "timeinseconds", "totalscore", scale=.7)
```

Comment: You should provide an example `df`.

Comment: How is the best way to do so?  Thx

Comment: Edit your question and copy enough of your `df` (as text) to make the code you wrote work. See here for more advice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Done.. thanks for the link

Comment: I doubt that `pointplot` is the tool you want to be using here.

Comment: Why not and what would I want to be using?

Comment: A complete guide is provided here: https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/blog_assets/Python_Seaborn_Cheat_Sheet.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve your problem:

```
g = (g.map(sns.pointplot, "timeinseconds", "totalscore", scale=.7)
    .set(xticks=[3, 5, 6, 7, 9], xticklabels=[30, 60, 90, 120, 150]))
```

The `xticks` indicate the positions where you want to place the labels  (numbered from `0` to `n-1` where `n` is the original number of ticks), and `xticklabels` the actual labels.

You can certainly find a way to do it with less hard-coding.